# Debugging (understanding) Dalvik VM using Eclipse on x86

Tags: android, dalvik

I'd like to understand how Dalvik VM works using an interactive debugger like Eclipse.

For example, I'd like to see how Dalvik loads an app (dex file), how interprets the bytecode, and finally how it triggers JIT and run compiled code natively.

It'd be great if I can see such steps with a debugger.

In order to do that, I need to compile and run only Dalvik VM on an x86 Linux machine. Is it technically possible, without any Android platform?

If it's not possible, is there any testing environment for Dalvik to only see the interpreter or JIT to some extent?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to compile dalvik for the host environment. In fact, when you build recent versions of android, you most likely already have a host build of dalvik, that is used when pre-odexing the system image. Look for the dalvikvm executable in, e.g. out/host/linux-x86/bin.

Before you try to run dalvikvm on the host, you'll need to have the full framework built, and set the BOOTCLASSPAPTH environment variable to a colon-separated path to all the various bootclasspath framework jars.

Alternately, you can also debug dalvikvm on the device itself, using gdbserver.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug native applications in an IDE on an Android device, it is not that straight forward.

Please check [Debugging Android native applications](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/07/debugging-android-native-applications.html) for step by step tutorial.